# Sencha Touch 2 DataView itemtaphold not firing

Tags: events, sencha-touch-2

For the life of me I'm unable to get my dataview to fire an itemtaphold event no matter how I attach the event handler. The itemtap event fires just fine. The closest i've been able to come is to use the longpress on the dom elements but that doesn't give me a reference to my control, just the dom element. Is the itemtaphold event broken for dataview on sencha touch 2 commercial?

**BrowserGrid.js:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.BrowserGrid', {
extend: 'Ext.dataview.DataView',
xtype: 'browsergrid',


requires: [
    'MyApp.view.BrowserGridItem',
    'Ext.dataview.*',
    'Ext.plugin.*'
],

config: {
    useComponents: true,
    cls: 'browser-grid',
    defaultType: 'browsergriditem',
    scrollable:{
        direction: 'vertical',
        directionLock: true
    },
    plugins :[{xclass:'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',autoPaging: true}],
    listeners: 
    {
        itemtaphold: function() { console.log('tapped'); }
    }
    }   
});
```

**BrowserGridItem.js**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.BrowserGridItem', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.component.DataItem',
    xtype : 'browsergriditem',

    config: {

        cls: 'browser-grid-item',
        dataMap: {
            getName: {
                setHtml: 'FILE_NAME'
            },
            getImage: {
                setSrc: 'IMG_URL'
            }
        },
        name: {
            cls: 'x-name'
        },
        image: {
            height:150,
            width: 150,
            flex:1
        },
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'center'
        }
    },
    applyImage: function(config) {
        return Ext.factory(config, Ext.Img, this.getImage());
    },
    updateImage: function(newImage, oldImage) {
        if (newImage) {
            this.add(newImage);
        }

        if (oldImage) {
            this.remove(oldImage);
        }
    },
    applyName: function(config) {
        return Ext.factory(config, Ext.Component, this.getName());
    },
    updateName: function(newName, oldName) {
        if (newName) {
            this.add(newName);
        }

        if (oldName) {
            this.remove(oldName);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please post your code ?

Comment: @roadRunner: as requested, I've added some of my code to my original post.

Comment: Working fine for me.. : http://www.senchafiddle.com/#7XerF